# VBA to work down column?

Tags: vba, excel

I have code which is working, just not quite how I want it to! Currently I have managed to get this to work on one cell.

I need to work down a column of data - column 'G' (only 6 rows), before ending when the data finishes.

I know I have to change the part where the code says 'target = cells (2,7)', but not what I need to write in place of this.

*EDIT* I'm writing this code to update a stock table, so the data in col G is items sold, and I need this to then match the item code in col A, deduct it from a list in col E of current stock. I've got that much to work, but only for the data in cell G2, or (2,7) in code. *EDIT*

```
Sub Order()
rowdata = 1
Do While Cells(rowdata, 1) <> ""
    rowdata = rowdata + 1
Loop
dataend = rowdata - 1
rowwrite = rowdata + 2
Cells(rowwrite, 1) = "Item Code"
For col = 1 To 3
    Cells(rowwrite, col) = Cells(1, col)
Next col
rowwrite = rowwrite + 1

target = Cells(2, 7)

For rowdata = 2 To dataend
    If Cells(rowdata, 1) = target Then
        Cells(rowdata, 5) = Cells(rowdata, 5) - 1
    End If
Next 

If Cells(rowdata, 5) = Cells(rowdata, 4) Then
    For col = 1 To 3
        Cells(rowwrite, col) = Cells(rowdata, col)
    Next col
    rowwrite = rowwrite + 1
End If
End sub
```

Comment: You should put your code between the Do While word and the Loop word.  Those few lines are counting how much data you have, but you can instead just execute your code at the same time.  As for specifics, I don't really know what you are trying to accomplish so I can't give very specific code to solve your problem.

Comment: Have updated the question now with some more info, hope this may help

Answer (score 0):

this might help:

```
Dim rowDataMax As Long

 'yields the number of "rows" in column "A"
rowDataMax = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To rowDataMax
 'Do code here
 'i.e, Cells(i, 7) = ...
Next i
```